# Set default font family in React Native Expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, react-router, react-navigation

I am trying to set default font(Lato-Regular) in RN Expo project.

I am using setCustomText to achieve this. https://github.com/Ajackster/react-native-global-props

This approach worked when running in non-expo project like a charm but now I am moving my project to Expo and seem to have a problem with default font for the app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Styles } from 'react-native'
import { Root } from './src/config/router'
import {
  setCustomText
} from 'react-native-global-props'

import { Font } from 'expo'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      currentTab: null,
      fontLoaded: false
    }
  }

  getCurrentRouteName(navigationState) {
    if (!navigationState) {
      return null;
    }
    const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index]
    if (route.routes) {
      return this.getCurrentRouteName(route)
    }
    return route.routeName;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     Font.loadAsync({
       'Lato-Regular': require('./src/assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf')
     });
     this.setState({
       fontLoaded: true
     }, 
     () => this.defaultFonts());

}

  defaultFonts(){
    const customTextProps = {
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Lato-Regular'
      }
    }
    setCustomText(customTextProps)
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this);
    return (
      this.state.fontLoaded ?
      <Root
      screenProps={{currentScreen: this.state.currentTab}}
      /> : null
  )
  }
}

export default App
```

But I get this error:

[image]

What might be the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are not waiting the font to be loaded, you call `setState` instantly after requesting the font. You have to wait the `Font.loadAsync` Promise to be resolved.

```
componentDidMount() {
  Font.loadAsync({
    'Lato-Regular': require('./src/assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf')
  })
    .then(() => {
       this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
       this.defaultFonts();
    });
}
```

You can also use the `async/await` syntax.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'Lato-Regular': require('./src/assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf')
  })
  this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  this.defaultFonts();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't know `react-native-global-props`, learned something too :)